# Google Sheets - Insert text automatically when cell is not empty

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, textjoin

Is there any possible way to insert "000" when I enter values in a cell. There is row called Cost where the value always ends with "000". There are thousands of rows which I need manually enter the values. Lets in Cell B30 if I enter 120 it should look like 120000. Please guide me through or let me know if there is any script that can allow me achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B); B1:B*1000; ))
```